# google sparesheets Parameter passing question

Tags: google-apps-script

when input string is work, 
but input ref value doesn't work, why?

```js
function IsInArray(CompareValue,CompareArr,TPart,FPart) 
{
  var output = FPart
  var ar = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("RefData!A:A").getValues()
  
  for (var i in ar)
  {
   if (ar[i] == CompareValue){output = TPart}
  }
  return output
  
}

// =IsInArray(E2,RefData!A:A,"T","F")

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange("RefData!A:A").getValues()
// output = T

// ↑ can retruns Tpart, ↓ truns to CompareArr doesn't work

SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRange(CompareArr).getValues()
// output = #ERROR
```

Comment: Can I ask you about `truns to CompareArr doesn't work`? So can you provide the script for calling the function of `IsInArray`?

Comment: =IsInArray(E2,RefData!A:A,"T","F") , 

[ getRange("RefData!A:A") , result = T]
[getRange(CompareArr) , result = #ERROR]

Comment: Thank you for replying. If you want to use `IsInArray` as a custom function, please use `RefData!A:A` as a string like `"RefData!A:A"`. So it's `=IsInArray(E2,"RefData!A:A","T","F")`. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)

Comment: thank for you helping, since inputer need add " "always, is not too convenient, if I want to fix this issue in script, how to do?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize my proposal was not useful for your situation. Although I cannot understand about `inputer need add " "always, is not too convenient`, for example, how about putting `RefData!A:A` to a cell of "B1" or other and using it as `=IsInArray(E2,B$1,"T","F")`?

Comment: actually, your reply already solve my problem.
thanks for your help. @ w @